# ASP.NET OnClick not firing in Repeater.ItemTemplate that has a custom control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, repeater

Title is a bit of a mouthful, but I'm a bit stuck on this issue.

I have a search result page with has a custom control that has a `Repeater`. The `ItemTemplate` in the repeater is a `PlaceHolder` so I can construct the Item in a particular format; more specifically, I have a string of 'diseases' that come in the form of `Disease1|disease2|disease3` and need to be given links for each disease.

Now for some code:

The following is the **SearchResultControl.ascx**

```
<asp:Panel ID="SearchResultPanel" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
        onitemcreated="Repeater1_ItemCreated" 
        onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemTemplatePlaceHolder" runat="server">
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="6"><hr /></td>
        </tr>
        </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

The code behind: **SearchResultControl.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.DataItem != null)
    {
        PlaceHolder placeHolder = e.Item.FindControl("ItemTemplatePlaceHolder") as PlaceHolder;
        Control searchResultItem = Page.LoadControl("SearchResultItem.ascx");

        DataRow row = (e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView).Row;

        if (row != null)
        {
            string diseaseState = row["DiseaseStates"] as string;
            searchResultItem.GetType().GetProperty("DiseaseStates").SetValue(searchResultItem, diseaseState, null);

            placeHolder.Controls.Add(searchResultItem);
        }
    }
}
```

(Full disclosure, I got this idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128083/dynamically-adding-controls-in-asp-net-repeater))

The SetValue calls the DiseaseStates property in **SearchResultItem** which in turn calls the following method to build the links, set the text, and the events:

```
private void BuildDiseaseStateLabels(string diseaseStates)
{
    PlaceHolder placeHolder = FindControl("DiseaseStatePlaceHolder") as PlaceHolder;
    string[] diseaseStateSplit = diseaseStates.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    int count = diseaseStateSplit.Length;
    foreach (string diseaseState in diseaseStateSplit)
    {
        LinkButton diseaseStateLink = new LinkButton();
        diseaseStateLink.Text = diseaseState;
        //diseaseStateLink.Click += new EventHandler(OnDiseaseStateLinkClick);
        diseaseStateLink.CommandArgument = "<%# Eval(\"PatientID\")+ \";\" + Eval(\"PatientStatus\")+ \";\" + Eval(\"Age\")+ \";\" + Eval(\"DiseaseStates\")%>";
        diseaseStateLink.CommandName = "OnDiseaseStateLinkClick";
        //diseaseStateLink.Command += new CommandEventHandler(OnDiseaseStateLinkClick);

        placeHolder.Controls.Add(diseaseStateLink);

        if (count != 0)
        {
            Label splitLabel = new Label();
            splitLabel.Text = "|";
            placeHolder.Controls.Add(splitLabel);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the layout for the **SearchResultItem**

```
<div id="SearchResultItemDiv" class="MainSearchResultItem">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DiseaseStatePlaceHolder" runat="server">
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Initially I tried setting the `Click` event, but that doesn't work at all. I then set the `CommandArgument` and `CommandName` but that didn't seem to do the trick. I figured the `Command` event might need to be set, but again, no luck. I should note that when a link is clicked the `Repeater1_ItemCreated` in **SearchResultControl.ascx.cs** is called. But since there is no data in `e.Item.DataItem` is null and I lose the results.

In one of the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940206/imagebutton-in-asp-net-repeater-does-not-fire-onclick-eventhandler) regarding the same issue, it was suggested that the `OnItemCommand` be added, but even that doesn't get called.

I also read [A Stumper of an ASP.NET Question](http://scottonwriting.net/sowBlog/archive/0000/00/00/162928.aspx) and [A Stumper of an ASP.NET Question: SOLVED!](http://scottonwriting.net/sowBlog/archive/0000/00/00/162929.aspx), to no avail.

What could I possibly be doing wrong? All of the correct event hookups seem there, I'm checking for `IsPostBack` and not doing `DataBind()` again. *blaaargharaggh*

Help is always greatly appreciate.

Comment: For others that may fall in this issue, please take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33022709/447558

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're running into this issue because the `LinkButton` controls are recreated too late in the page lifecycle. You have to remember that when the page is posted back, the control technically does not exist anymore, so the event handler cannot be fired.

If you can recreate the `LinkButton` controls somewhere before the `Page_Load` event is reached, like `OnInit` for example, everything should work fine.

For simple pages the above usually works very well, but there are circumstances where recreating controls during `OnInit` requires a lot of overhead, such as storing counters or arrays in ViewState so you can keep track of the controls that need to be recreated after postback. In these situations I would suggest taking a look at the `DynamicControlsPlaceHolder` by Denis Bauer. This control is capable of persisting dynamic controls without any addtional code required, which is pretty awesome.

Here's a link to the latest version:
http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx

Comment: Oh...That makes sense. I moved the setting of the DataSource into `OnInit` like you suggested and that seems to work. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad you got it working. You should check out the `DynamicControlsPlaceHolder` sometime too! It's a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you're not doing the `DataBind()` again.

Because you're building the buttons on the fly, when the page post backs, the buttons haven't been created and are unable to work out which click event it should be firing.

Try getting rid of the `IsPostBack` check, so each time the page loads, you're re-build the `repeater`.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.