# onclick not being fired in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a button within the ItemTemplate of my ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="notificiationsList" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<button type="submit" commandargument='<%# Eval("offerID") %>' onclick="Accept_Click" runat="server" >Accept</button>
</ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then I have a breakpoint in my code:

```
protected void Accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  .... // breakpoint here
}
```

However when I debug the page does nothing and it doesn't reach the breakpoint for some reason?

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding autopostback="true" to the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how you are binding your ListView. I created the following code with a few tweaks to what you have above.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvNotification" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAccept" runat="server" OnClick="Accept_Click" CommandArgument="test" Text="Accept" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Binding the ListView:

```
List<string> tL = new List<string>(){ "this", "and", "that"};

lvNotification.DataSource = tL;
lvNotification.DataBind();
```

And I reused your click code:

```
protected void Accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // breakpoint here
}
```

I was able to hit the breakpoint without issue.

Comment: How did you get this working without surrounding it in a form tag?

Comment: Also is it possible to place the LinkButton element into a `<div>Next to this text (link button here)</div>` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your aspx page looks like. If it's just a webform without a masterpage then you would put this code inside the form tags. If you have a masterpage then it could be in the masterpage or within a contentplace holder on another page. If that make sense. You should also be able to format with divs or whatever html you need for layout.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was a statement in the pageload that causes the ListView to be binded again.
This causes the initial event lost.
Check the Page_Load just to be sure :)

HTH,
Milton