# trying Image Button in repeater Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have a problem using imageButton in a Repeater.I tried alot of method and didnt fix the problem.I used the repeater item command still not working.when i click on the imageButton nothing happen.

`<asp:ImageButton  ID="ImageButton1"  runat="server"  Height="200px" Width="150px"  ImageUrl='<%#"~/imageHandler.ashx?Mid=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Mid")%>'  CommandName="img" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Mid") %>'  />`

```
  protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        ModalPopupExtender mpe = (ModalPopupExtender)e.Item.FindControl("mpe");
        LinkButton Lbtn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1");
       switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "btn1":

                Session["id"] = Lbtn.CommandArgument.ToString();

                mpe.Show();

                break;
            case "img":
                Response.Write("event is fired");
                break;

            default:
                break;
```

Comment: Seems to be duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940206/imagebutton-in-asp-net-repeater-does-not-fire-onclick-eventhandler

Comment: i dont want to use a linkbutton i just want to handle the event when i click on the imageButton.And I used repeater item command and set a command name for imagebutton  without using onclick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the snippet below. Your LinkButton code seems to be correct, but did you add the `OnItemCommand` to the Repeater?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandName="img" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Mid") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string commandArgument = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

    if (e.CommandName == "img")
    {
        Response.Write("event is fired: " + commandArgument);
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "btn1")
    {
        Session["id"] = commandArgument;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I have the onItemCommand in the repeater and avery thing is working well and btn1 is working except the image button not doing anything and here is my imagebutton '               <asp:ImageButton  ID="ImageButton1"  runat="server"  Height="200px" Width="150px"  ImageUrl='<%#"~/imageHandler.ashx?Mid=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Mid")%>'  CommandName="img" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Mid") %>'  />
'

Comment: Test my snippet. If it works (and it does) expand from there.