# How to fetch values inside a parent repeater on link button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

On a link button click , I want to fetch the value of a hidden field which is contained inside a repeater. Below is my code

aspx page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn1" runat="server" OnClick="btnClick"/>
              <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn1" runat="server" Value="true"/>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


CodeBehind:

protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //How to get the value of the hidden field hdn1 over here
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying Image Button in repeater Asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325839/trying-image-button-in-repeater-asp-net)

Comment: Nope. not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: to get value from user control you need a form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

Find Row of repeater from Button as sender then find Hidden field inside (`RepeaterItem`) repeater row

```
protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LinkButton   lnkBtn1= sender as LinkButton;
   RepeaterItem Rptitem = (RepeaterItem)lnkBtn1.NamingContainer;
   HiddenField  hdn1 =  (HiddenField  ) Rptitem.FindControl("hdn1");
   string hiddenvalue=hdn1.Value;

}
```